# Meteor.setTimeout() issue in Meteor Timers?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I did a sample example on `Meteor.setTimeout()` using `Meteor`. In this example i get an error. I didn't have any idea about this.So please see the below code,error and suggest me how to do?

Error :

```
Exception in setTimeout callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?8ec262df25783897eaad01255bc8bd1ca4e78b24:773:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?8ec262df25783897eaad01255bc8bd1ca4e78b24:358:45
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?8ec262df25783897eaad01255bc8bd1ca4e78b24:801:22
```

JS Code :

```
   if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
  Meteor.setTimeout(Test("10"), 1000);
  Meteor.setInterval(Test1, 1000);

  Template.hello.greeting = function () 
  {
    return "Welcome to timerapp.";
  };

  Template.hello.events
  ({
    'click input' : function () 
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");

        //Test();
    }
  });
}
function Test(x)
{
   console.log("*** Test() ***"+x);
}
function Test1()
{
   console.log("*** Test1() ***");
}
if (Meteor.isServer)
 {

  Meteor.startup(function ()
  {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });


}
```

Comment: `Meteor.setTimeout` is only necessary on the server, because server code must run within a Fiber. There are no Fibers on the client, so you can just use the regular global `window.setTimeout`. That said, you must pass a function object as @Tobold pointed out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that `setTimeout` expects a function as a first parameter but you are passing the result of evaluating `Test("10")` which is "undefined".

You can solve the issue by wrapping your call to `Test1` in an anonymous function:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){Test("10");}, 1000);
```

Comment: This worked for exactly what I needed it for. Ideally you would make an actual function to call, but this worked for the little snippet needed.